# When do two separate accounts become merged as one?

Tags: support, login, authentication

Previously, I had two separate Stack Exchange accounts. One was work related, the other was for personal use. For some reason, StackExchange merged those two accounts as one. (I cannot recall or explain the reason why.)

So, I am concerned about the following:

Both my wife and I have our own StackExchange accounts, each registered to a different email address. Would these accounts be merged if we use the same network or computer? If so, how can we let StackExchange know that these accounts should be separate?

Comment: Dennis, I have rewritten your question. Please let me know if my understanding or assumptions are wrong! :)

Comment: Thank you perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> had two separate Stack Exchange accounts. One was work related, the other was for personal use. For some reason, StackExchange merged those two accounts as one

No. This happens only if you've logged in as the first user & add then added the second account's email address to the first account's login credentials.

> Both my wife and I have our own StackExchange accounts, each registered to a different email address. Would these accounts be merged if we use the same network or computer?

Typically, they won't be merged unless you proceed to do the steps as mentioned above.

> If so, how can we let StackExchange know that these accounts should be separate?

Don't login from two accounts at the same time.

Comment: OK - i will ask my wife to have permission to use her account from my same browser and same desktop/laptop. To post together question. I would appreciate if my wife account is never ever patched with my as husband account.

Comment: @DennisRitchie Like I said, Stack Exchange doesn't know or doesn't care if two accounts are related or not - there's no way to distinguish them. The only way multiple accounts are treated as single is if you *explicitly* merge them by already being logged into one account and then add the other email account

Comment: Well Thank you. that was not my case i had different work account and all merge into one. Which is now like a spam, because i did not myself did it. It was done by Stack. So now making it clear if Wife and Husband is equal in Stack Law.

Comment: But isn't the question ban IP based? Or doesn't that merge automatically?

Comment: @Sathya I fixed Dennis' question. Do you think you can provide a new answer to reflect the changes? :P

Comment: Did so, @iglvzx